# Changing wallpaper with terminal command on macOS

Tags: shell, command-line, zsh, macos

It's possible to change the wallpaper through the command line with the command

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to set desktop picture to POSIX file "<absolute_path_to_file>"'
```

where of course `<absolute_path_to_file>` is just a placeholder for the full path of the image to be used as background.

I'm trying to use this command to write a zsh function, but I'm having some troubles figuring out how to escape the variable name (for ex `$1`) to get proper substitution. For example, using the function

```
change_wallpaper () { osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to set desktop picture to POSIX file "$1"' }
```

and then

```
$ change_wallpaper /Users/noibe/Wallpapers/wallpaper.jpg
```

doesn't work, and I get the error:

```
33:48: execution error: Finder got an error: AppleEvent handler failed. (-10000)
```

probably because `$1` is not being substitued with the path but it is passed as a literal string. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2):

Parameter expansion cannot take place within single quotes.

Try:

```
change_wallpaper() {
    osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to set desktop picture to POSIX file "'"$1"\"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work, escaping the double quotes and switching the single quotes with double quotes:

```
change_wallpaper() {
    osascript -e "tell application \"Finder\" to set desktop picture to POSIX file \"$1\""
}
```